# How to properly stretch image in Monogame screen

Tags: monogame

I am a beginner in Monogame and C#. I am making my first game.
I have changed the screen dimensions in Game1 constructor. I am drawing a sprite where I have set the Rectangle width and height to width and height of the screen to fit it on the screen. I am creating a scrolling background for which I have to change the position of the sprite. I am setting the position to Vector. Zero which is making the sprite stretched towards the right.

```
Game1
//member variables
        Vector2 stage;
        Texture2D fbTexture;
        private List<ScrollingBackground> sb;
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            //change the screen size
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 900;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 600;
            Window.Title = "Flappy Bird Returns";
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            stage = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, 
                    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);

            //Day Background
            Texture2D dayTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/background-day");
            Vector2 daySpeed = new Vector2(1, 0);
            sb = new List<ScrollingBackground>()
            {
                //set the width and height to be the same as the screen 
                //dimensions then this will 
                //stretch the image past its original dimensions to fit.
                new ScrollingBackground(this, 
                spriteBatch, 
                dayTex,
                new Vector2(0,0), 
                new Rectangle(0,0, (int)stage.X, (int)stage.Y),
                daySpeed)

            };
            foreach (ScrollingBackground scrollbackg in sb)
                this.Components.Add(scrollbackg);
          }
```

```
//ScrollingBackground.cs
private SpriteBatch spritebatch;
        private Texture2D tex;
        private Vector2 position1;
        private Vector2 speed;
        private Rectangle srcRect;

        public ScrollingBackground(Game game, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D tex, Vector2 pos, Rectangle srcRect, Vector2 speed) : base(game)
        {
            this.spritebatch = spriteBatch;
            this.tex = tex;
            this.position1 = pos;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.srcRect = srcRect;
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            spritebatch.Begin();
            spritebatch.Draw(tex, position1, srcRect, Color.White);
            spritebatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

[image: With position1 in Draw]

```
//Without position1
spritebatch.Draw(tex, srcRect, Color.White);
```

[image: Without position1 in Draw]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give an argument to the `float scale` parameter. This means you'll need to use a more specific signature for this method :

```cs
SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Rectangle? sourceRectangle, Color color, float rotation, Vector2 origin, **float scale**, SpriteEffects effects, float layerDepth)
```

At the same time, you'll need to specify default values for every other parameter. For example, here's how you'd write that same Draw() method with the aforementioned method signature :

```cs
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spritebatch.Begin();
    spritebatch.Draw(tex, position1, srcRect, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 2f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    spritebatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Here, I put your texture to 2x it's original size. Change that `2f` to the size you want. Keep in mind the final size will be the width/height values of your `srcRect` multiplied by that number.