# Monogame how to resize an image

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am new to creating games using monogame and I am stuck on trying to figure out how to resize a image i just added. Here is what I have so far.

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        StickFigure = Content.Load<Texture2D>("StickFigure");
        
       
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            stickPos.Y -= 10;
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            stickPos.Y += 10;
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            stickPos.X -= 10;
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            stickPos.X += 10;
        }


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();

        _spriteBatch.Draw(StickFigure, stickPos, Color.White);

        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can change the size of this image so that I can scale factor the size. Thanks!

Comment: Can this answer help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058586/how-to-properly-stretch-image-in-monogame-screen

Answer (score 1):

The MonoGame documentation for the SpriteBatch class (linked below) lists several Draw methods that include a scaling parameter.
Alternatively, I have a vague memory that simply drawing from a specific source rectangle to a specific destination rectangle might invoke scaling automatically, but I could be wrong there.

[SpriteBatch](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this depending on the requirements:

1. If the movement speed is always an integer (as in your example code speed = 10, very fast at 60 fps), change `stickPos` to a Rectangle.  Movement directions are restricted by integer speeds, at the minimum speed of one, it can only move in 8 directions (45 degrees), 2 is 16 directions (22.5), ... Fastest. Collisions are provided by Rectangle.Intersect.
2. Mirror the Vector2 in the Rectangle.  All directions and speeds are possible. Used with Vector2 velocities and collisions as described in #1.
3. Use the scale parameter of the Draw method.  Only use this for cosmetic items, since collision scaling must be calculated separately.

Other Notes:

Store the speed in a variable or const. A single change instead of four.

Store the KeyboardState once per step: `var ks = Keyboard.GetState();`

---

The following code gives examples of each technique given the source texture size of 64x64 being drawn at 32x32.

1.

```
    // Class Level
    Rectangle stickPos = new Rectangle(0,0,32,32);
    int speed = 10; // const int speed = 10; if it will never change at runtime.

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        var ks = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            stickPos.Y -= speed;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            stickPos.Y += speed;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            stickPos.X -= speed;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            stickPos.X += speed;
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();

        _spriteBatch.Draw(StickFigure, stickPos, Color.White);

        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);

}
```

2. 

```
    // Class Level
    Vector2 stickPos = new Vector2();
    Rectangle DrawRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,32,32);
    float speed = 10; //any float value

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        var ks = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            stickPos.Y -= speed;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            stickPos.Y += speed;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            stickPos.X -= speed;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            stickPos.X += speed;
        }
        // repeat the following code anytime sickPos changes.
        DrawRectangle.X = (int)stickPos.X;
        DrawRectangle.Y = (int)stickPos.Y;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();

        _spriteBatch.Draw(StickFigure, DrawRectangle, Color.White);

        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

3. 

```
    // Class Level
    Vector2 stickPos = new Vector2(0,0);
    float speed = 10; //any float value
    Vector2 scale = new Vector2(.5f,.5f); // 64 to 32 == .5f

    // use Update changes in #2

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();
/* This is the full overloaded Draw call used from SpriteBatch.cs line 179 in the following line.
public void Draw (Texture2D texture,
                Vector2 position,
                Rectangle? sourceRectangle,
                Color color,
                float rotation,
                Vector2 origin,
                Vector2 scale,
                SpriteEffects effects,
                float layerDepth)
*/

        _spriteBatch.Draw(StickFigure, stickPos, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None,0);

        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```